# How to determine a function that make these operators, orthogonal projectors

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, projection-matrices

Verify if we can find a function $\beta(x) \in C^\infty$ such as the operators $T_{\pm}$ defined as

\begin{equation}
(T_{+}f)(x) = \beta(x)[ \beta(x)f(x)+\beta(-x)f(-x)]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(T_{-}f)(x) = \beta(-x) \left[ \beta(-x)f(x)-\beta(x)f(-x)\right]
\end{equation}

are orthogonal projectors $(P^2=P=P^*)$ and satisfies the follow

\begin{equation}
\beta(x) = \left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
x>1 & 1\\
x<-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
T_+T_-=T_-T_+=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
T_++T_-=I
\end{equation}

I've been trying to obtain something using the definition of orthogonal projectors and even trying to represent everything as matrix but i don't really get anything, i think it's a problem of misconception but i've been stuck with this problem for days reading and reading about this subject, help please!